# Numba slower when optionally returning arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I try to write a numba function, that optionally returns arrays, that are created inside the function. I found, that just the implementation of this option slows down the execution compared to the same function without the option of returning the arrays.

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True, nogil=True, cache=True)
def testfun1(array_in, arrays_out=np.empty((0,0), np.float64)):
    array_add_1 = array_in + 1
    array_add_2 = array_in + 2
    array_sum_1 = sum(array_add_1)
    array_sum_2 = sum(array_add_2)
    
    if arrays_out.shape == (10,len(array_in)):
        # write to an array
        arrays_out[0,:] = array_add_1
        arrays_out[1,:] = array_add_1
        arrays_out[2,:] = array_add_1
        arrays_out[3,:] = array_add_1
        arrays_out[4,:] = array_add_1
        
        arrays_out[5,:] = array_add_2
        arrays_out[6,:] = array_add_2
        arrays_out[7,:] = array_add_2
        arrays_out[8,:] = array_add_2
        arrays_out[9,:] = array_add_2
    
        
    return (array_sum_1, array_sum_2)

@jit(nopython=True, nogil=True, cache=True)
def testfun2(array_in, arrays_out=np.empty((0,0), np.float64)):
    array_add_1 = array_in + 1
    array_add_2 = array_in + 2
    array_sum_1 = sum(array_add_1)
    array_sum_2 = sum(array_add_2)
    
    if arrays_out.shape == (10,len(array_in)):
        array_add_1 = 0 # do something
        array_add_2 = 0 # do something
        
    return (array_sum_1, array_sum_2)


array_in = np.arange(0,10000)
```

Timing gives me:

```
%timeit testfun1(array_in) # 70.1 µs ± 346 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit testfun2(array_in) # 69.6 µs ± 217 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

(Please note, that this is a really small scaled example. In my actual code, the time difference is much more noticeable because of more and bigger arrays to optionally return)

So basically both functions do the same, as no `arrays_out` variable with correct size is passed to the functions. But why is testfun1 slower?

Do you know an alternative to code a function, that optionally returns arrays but won't slow down the execution when arrays should not be returned?

Thanks and best regards,

Scooba

Comment: I get very different behavior when I test this - I get about 12 microseconds for testfun1 and about 115 microseconds for testfun2. (I'm guessing changing the type of `array_add_1` and `array_add_2` in the `if` in `testfun2` inhibits optimizations.)

Comment: Somehow for my first run I experienced the same, testfun1 was much faster than testfun2. But for every other run it was like mentioned in my post.

Comment: I tested both functions with repeated `%timeit` calls and consistently saw `testfun1` run much faster.

Comment: "But why is testfun1 slower?" you should look the standard deviation: you cannot conclude this based on the provided information. They can run equally fast.

Comment: I got similar results to user2357112 initially (with many runs), and when I changed the function code, then I got the same results as you. I think you are measuring compilation artefacts. I succeed to reproduce this weird behaviour multiple times by re-oppenning the interpreter. The exact procedure is to copy past the first block of code, then the second block of code (twice since the first run is biased due to the compilation time), then repeat the operation again.

Comment: Last but not least, reverting the order of the `timeit` lines results in opposite effects. This confirm this is a compilation artefact. This is certainly due to LLVM-Lite (and actually certainly just LLVM). Please consider filling a bug on the GitLab of Numba about this. Besides this, I do not understand why you expect the timings to be significantly different between the two function.

Comment: Hmm, maybe the example is not ideal. I'll try to figure out a better one. I'm pretty sure, that there is an issue somewhere. In my original code, for which i first encountered this issue, I call a numba function that does some calculations on arrays and returns some values. So just like in my example. There, with writing to the array, timeit results in:
717 µs ± 3.57 µs;
719 µs ± 4.15 µs;
718 µs ± 4.21 µs.
And commenting out the code after if:
701 µs ± 3.97 µs;
706 µs ± 4.7 µs;
699 µs ± 4.92 µs